# my code isn't doing what I think it should, any ideas why?

Tags: javascript

this is supposed to repeat "working" in the console when the variable is true then stop when its false.
Idk why its not working, but I'm new to coding so it's probably pretty simple.

```
var isOn;

if(command === 'start'){
    isOn = true;
    console.log('isOn = true');
} 

if(command === 'stop'){
    isOn = false;
    console.log('isOn = false');
}

while (isOn == true){
    console.log('working');
}
```

Comment: Where is you defined the `command` variable?

Comment: here: client.on('message', message =>{
 if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

Comment: You can write a `console.log` to check what is the `command` value after you changed it.

Comment: Thx I'll try that